# Display of Table and Figure row alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I would like to align my table (raw data) and its graph as a figure next to it. I have looked at recommendations and guidelines to follow but I still miss to understand how to use them correctly.

I went over minipages but it seems to not be working properly. I think that it is due to my wrapfigure environment just above. And all figures turned black:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\thead{time\\ (min)} & \thead{A - number\\ of bacteria} \\
\hline
0     & 100 \\
3     & 200 \\
6     & 400 \\
9     & 800 \\
12    & 1600 \\
15    & 3200 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Display and representation of bacteria growth per 3
min time}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{bacteria.png}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Please help me, thank you very much ! Have a wonderful day

Comment: Could you give up a complet and compilable example ?

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry it wasn't clear, I don't know how to make it clearer because even I don't know what is happening. 

I would like to have the data table and graph aligned horizontally and appropriate in terms of size.

Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

- around wrapped figure had to be plain text
- caption had not to be inside `tabular` environment
- table is wider than half of text width

I suggest you to enclose table and figure in common float,  for example `figure`, make that float will be on appropriate distance below or above wrap figure and write column headers in two lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\thead{time\\ (min)} & \thead{A - number\\ of bacteria} \\
\hline
0     & 100 \\
3     & 200 \\
6     & 400 \\
9     & 800 \\
12    & 1600 \\
15    & 3200 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Table caption}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{bacteria.png}
\caption{Figure caption}
\end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
And result with original pictures. Used it in above MWE gives expected result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your assistance, I appreciate it very much. However, using your code, I noticed that the package '\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}' would make my figures turn black. Also I don't know the reason but my result does not look the same as yours. I don't know how to insert questions as a comment but my graph is not aligned with the table. It is shifted towards the top right corner... 
Thank you, sorry for any inconveniences

Comment: Option `demo` serves only replace your image, which I haven't. Just erase it.  If your image is wrong placed can means, that the image has white space around it. To see, if this is true, test my MWE with your image (with erased option`demo` , i.e.  with `\usepackage{graphicx}`)   with `\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{bacteria.png}}`.

Comment: I just tried and framed the graph into a box. It is still displaced towards the top right corner

Comment: `\fbox{...}` will not correct image placement, it will only show, if around image is empty space. Can you show me somewhere your image that I can see, what is going on?

Comment: How can I share you a screenshot in comments ?

Comment: In comment is not possible. Give me a link, where i can download it. I need original image, not screenshot. only if it is obtained such as I recommended in comment before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49062/discussion-between-arthur-pl-and-zarko).